# A column contains `Male` and `Female` and i want to change all female into male and viceversa

Tags: sql, sql-update

A column contains `Male` and `Female` and i want to change all female into male and viceversa.(I want to do this in single update.)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This:

```
UPDATE YourTableName SET ColumnName = CASE ColumnName  WHEN 'm' THEN 'f' ELSE 'm' END
```

I hope it will helpful for you.

And try (IFF) if you using sql-server 2012.

Try this link, It will help you about IIf in server 2012

http://sqlhints.com/2013/06/15/iif-logical-function-in-sql-server-2012/

Comment: can you elaborate IFF.

Answer (score 2):

It's all right but above case will update NULL values also (all NULL gender to 'm') better if we stay in safe by updating the values where 'm''f' exist:

```
UPDATE #tmp SET gender = CASE gender WHEN 'm' THEN 'f' WHEN 'f' THEN 'm' END
```

Comment: In my case, it works fine for me,anyway thank you for your suggesstion :)))))